# How to change the color of a particular element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and I need help. For our group project in University, we are making a mobile application which creates notes in which you can add title, content and so on.

In the note object, we wanted to add a button that allows the user to change the color of the note background, using a batch of 5 different colors: red, blue, green, orange, purple.

This is the design of the note: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMdZF.jpg

Now, this is what happens when you click on the Color button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiUH2.jpg

I want to make it such that, when one of the colors is clicked, the color of the note changes to that color and the button popup closes.

Could you help me out? How can I do it? Here is the code:

```
function addNewNote(className, title, content) {
    // if class is not specified, use a random colour class
    if (!className) {
        className = "colour" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
    }

    // add a new note to the end of the list
    notes.append(
        "<li>" +
            "<div class='" + className + "' >" +
                "<img class='hide' src='images/close.png'/>" +
                "<textarea class='note-title' placeholder='New Note' maxlength='10'/>" +
                "<textarea class='note-content' placeholder='Start typing...'/>" +
                "<button>" +
                    "<a href='#myPopup' data-rel='popup' class='note-button'>Color</a>" +
                    "<div data-role='popup' id='myPopup'>" +
                        "<h5>Choose colour:</h5>" +
                        "<a href class='red'>Red</a>" +
                        "<a href class='green'>Green</a>" +
                        "<a href class='blue'>Blue</a>" +
                        "<a href class='orange'>Orange</a>"+
                        "<a href class='purple'>Purple</a>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</button>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</li>"
    );

    // get the new note that's just been added and attach the click event handler to its close button
    var newNote = notes.find("li:last");
    newNote.find("img").click(function () {
        // remove the note and save
        newNote.remove();
        saveNotes();
    });

    // hook up event handlers to show/hide close button as appropriate
    addNoteEvent(newNote);

    // if a title is provided then set the title of the new note
    if (title) {
        // get the title textarea element and set its value
        newNote.find("textarea.note-title").val(title);
    }

    // if a content is provided then set the content of the new note
    if (content) {
        // get the content textarea element and set its value
        newNote.find("textarea.note-content").val(content);
    }

    // save
    saveNotes();
}
```

Everything is added to the note through `notes.append()`, and everything else is commented, hoping it can kind of help you out in understanding how it works.

It randomly creates the color for a note at first with the line:

```
// if class is not specified, use a random colour class
if (!className) {
    className = "colour" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
}
```

In the CSS, there's the `ul li div.colour1`, `ul li div.colour2` and so on until 5. (Cannot post the screenshot, I don't have 10 rep)

How can I do it?

Sorry for the long post and I hope it is understandable. If needed, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: what is the `className` value you are getting

Comment: @hunzaboy: I have tried putting a function in the document.ready() kind of like this:

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("red").click(function(){
    alert("it works!");
    });
    });

Obviously, just to check if the alert worked when clicking on "Red", which didn't

Comment: @brk:http://imgur.com/a/Uvqtb

Comment: use .red not red

Comment: check ITWitch's answer. You need to put the code at the bottom  of the page, just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try do something like this:

```
$(/* your query */).css('color', 'red');
```

Or eventually:

```
$(/* your query */).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly? Where and how should I put this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use data attribute in html tag and use respective color name or Hax code. remember if you are going to use color name directly then it should be available in style directly.

personally i prefer Hax code.

https://jsfiddle.net/tLtst05w/1/

example here

```
HTML

<div>
<a id="linkbackclr">hi</a>
<b>testing</b>
<button class="btnClick" data-backcolor="red">red</button>
<button class="btnClick" data-backcolor="green">green</button>
<button class="btnClick" data-backcolor="blue">blue</button>
<button class="btnClick" data-backcolor="orange">orange</button>
<button class="btnClick" data-backcolor="white">white</button>
</div>

JS

$(".btnClick").on("click",function(){
var mybackcolor = $(this).data("backcolor");
$("#linkbackclr").css('background-color', mybackcolor);
});
```

Comment: I like the idea, the problem is that I had to create the buttons in the notes.append in the JS file because they have to be attached to the note element.

If I create them in the HTML, they won't be attached to the note element everytime I create a new note

Comment: but as you mentioned already in your question you are having these buttons. https://imgur.com/a/17Pet ..

so you will just need to add class and on click event in js

Comment: Yes, but they are not really buttons. They are links (<a href>) as, if I try to put buttons, this happens: http://imgur.com/a/9xHJo

Comment: it doesnt matter. it is buttons or links. click event of javascript will always work on click of class. and i find you are adding class with color name in your question. so for adding one more class you can add one space and after that just add one more class name example : <a class="red newclassname">link</a>. like this

Answer (score 0):

it seems the problem is with this line itself.

```
className = "colour" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
```

so `className` will be colour+a randon number; For example colour1,colour2.. so on. So you have to maintan a css class by this name.

Instead you can create a function which will generate color in hexcode and will be applied

```
   //This will return a random color
    var colorName = function createCol() {
      for (var col = "#", b = 0; 6 > b; b++) {
        col += "0123456789ABCDEF" [Math.floor(16 * Math.random())];
      }
      return col
    };
```

Then `<div style='color:" + colorName+ "' >"`

Comment: I cannot touch the className attribute, as it is inherited from the command that loads the notes:

http://imgur.com/a/Uvqtb

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** to make it work...

Try changing your `notes.append` this way:

- add a class to `li` and `li div`
- change button color classes into id, and add a uniform class for each

Then, add some click event for the color links:

```
$('.colorChoice').click(function(){
    var color = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert('color = '+color);

    var target = $(this).closest('li.someNote div.someNote-box');
    $(target).removeClass();
    $(target).addClass('someNote-box '+color);
});
```

For this to work, you must have some CSS like this:

```
.red { background-color: red; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.orange { background-color: orange; }
.purple { background-color: purple; }
```

[Here's the working JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/flamedenise/jgpxuozL/) Feel free to edit it to suit what you really need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I have tried with what you suggested, but sadly it is not working. The line that does not work is this one:

$(this).closest('li.someNote div').css({'background-color':color});

I have tried the different version that you put commented, but that one does not work as well.

I am sure this is the issue because I have changed the second line to alert(color); just to check if it worked, and it successfully showed the text associated to the color I clicked.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed something. Fixed everything above, and also added a working JSFiddle demo.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for bothering. I have tried what you have written but it does not work for me. 

I have included in this screenshot what I have changed to my functions but the result is the same: the color of the window does not change:

http://imgur.com/a/SQB8J

Also, there's another issue that I encountered sadly, and I'm really sorry for going kind of overboard but I hope you can help me out.

This is the mess that happens when I click on the button that creates a new note:

http://imgur.com/a/UlrwW

And I think I know why, because even though the div is a popup appears anyways.

Comment: Sorry, I finished the characters on the previous comment.I don't really know how to fix the second part because it would mean that I have to call the <div> taking care of the popup from another part of the program, but I don't know how since you cannot include a div in a function.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your problem is: when you click on "colors" pop-up in note 1, the "colors" pop-up in note 2 also appears. Is this the problem you also want to fix?

Comment: Also, are you using bootstrap for your pop-up? Or some other JS library?

Comment: No, the issue is that when I click on the button to create a new note the popup appears automatically, without me needing to click on the "color" button, making it a mess.

Also, I am using the jQuery mobile library:

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, I now see what you mean. I have updated the JSFiddle. It's working now, but still with a little bug. See for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/flamedenise/jgpxuozL/

Comment: Hi again, thank you very much, I haven't included the code yet but just trying on JSFiddle I can see that there's a bug, if you have more than one note if you try to change the color it changes the color of a different note. I'll have a try on the code tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: Hi again, sorry but I've managed only now to test everything.

Still, nothing seems to work. The problem is that the notes I create are on the second page (the button to create them is on the first page) and are created in the .js file, through the notes.append function.

It seems like it doesn't call the div for the note correctly, even the notes graphic content is different: http://imgur.com/a/CdWac

As you can see, the text boxes are different on the new note created.

Is it possible that it doesn't load the <div> correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have noticed that it doesn't work well with `,append()`. You should use `.clone()` instead, like what I did in the JSFiddle.